# If “God is not the author of confusion” (1 Corinthians 14:33), how is Genesis 11:7 to be understood?

Tags: genesis, contradiction, 1-corinthians

> 1 Corinthians 14:33 God is not the author of confusion.
>
> Genesis 11:7 Come, let us go down and confuse their language.
>
> Deuteronomy 28:20 The LORD will send on you curses, confusion and rebuke in everything you put your hand to.

Comment: This is like saying  "I, even I, am the Lord; And there is no savior besides Me. (Isaiah 43:11) And at Luke 2:11, "for today in the city of David there has been born for you a SAVIOR, who is Christ the Lord. Did it ever occur to you to read the context of Genesis 11:7 and figure out why He confused their language? Just saying!

Comment: Superficial approach: The confusion of Genesis 11 (Tower of Babel) is a punishment. But why would God want to punish those that follow Him (like the Corinthians) ? Slightly deeper approach: The people of Genesis 11 acted against God, as such, they entered a state of confusion, due to their estrangement from Him, in Whom there is no confusion. Starting of as one tongue, they became many. The Corinthians, on the other hand, starting of as many nations (living in the same multicultural city), ended up as one (Christian) people, by drawing closer to God.

Comment: The raising of a tower to heaven would have caused confusion regarding God's true purpose in creating humanity. God overturned this project of confusion by muddling up the communications of the perpetrators of the confusion project.

Comment: It is good to examine who it is that claims God is not the author of confusion and his witness. The same also claims God sends strong delusion. Beware the leaven of the Pharisees.

Answer (score 2):

1 Corinthians 14:33 (LEB), italicized words are provided by translation for clarity:

> For God is not *a God of* disorder but of peace.

This "disorder" is the Greek word ἀκαταστασία *akatastasia* "disorder; insurrection". It's used 5 times in the New Testament. It's sometimes grouped with "jealousy" and "selfish ambition" (2 Co 12:20; Jas 3:16); also with "wars" (Lk 21:9) and "beatings" (2 Co 6:5), among sufferings in general. This is a different "confusion" than in Ge 11.

This "peace" is εἰρήνη *eirēnē* "peace". It's used a lot more than ἀκαταστασία is. Jesus contrasts εἰρήνη with war and division ("a sword" Mat 10:34; "division" Lk 12:51). In Ro 14:13-20 (LEB), Paul uses it to teach the Romans to be willing to not eat certain foods in order to promote communal peace:

> So then, let us pursue ⌊**what promotes peace**⌋ [εἰρήνη] and ⌊what edifies one another⌋. Do not destroy the work of God on account of food.

Paul's meaning in 1 Co is that they (the Corinthians) don't need to fight to get their turn to speak. Everybody can get a chance to speak if they simply wait patiently for their turn. Ge 11:7 doesn't contradict Paul's theology because the "confusions" are different. In Genesis, "confusion" is miscommunication/misunderstanding. In 1 Corinthians, "confusion" is civil unrest, arguing, etc. Someone else has already pointed out the Greek versions of Genesis have a different word than ἀκαταστασία for "confusion".

Answer (score 0):

For God is not a God of confusion but of peace. As in all the churches of the saints,

is God's positive work or affirmative work. What's God doing in the universe, today: what's His purpose, work, and activity? He's **building His assembly** Mt 16:18, which is His Son's Body, the fullness of the One who fills all in all. That's the **peace** and order: the meeting of the saints, locally, in 1 Cor 14.

And Jehovah said, Behold, they are one people, and they all have one language; and this is only the beginning of what they will do; and now nothing which they purpose to do will be kept from them. Come, let Us go down and there confound their language, that they may not understand one another’s speech. So Jehovah scattered them from there over the surface of all the earth, and they ceased building the city.

Gen 11:6-8 is Jehovah, triune Jehovah's **judgment**. On the negative side, reacting to the world's independence and rebellion at Babel, 11:4. So "not authoring confusion" refers to His "positive" work.